# How to do it right Singleton for Application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

**This is my code but it doesn't work**

```
    class App : Application() {
    
        override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
            super.attachBaseContext(base)
        }
    
        companion object {
            val instance: App = App()
        }
    }
```

**I need him that I worked with SharedPreferences.Because without a context it will be wrong**

```
     SharedPreferences preferences = AppSingleton.getInstance().getSharedPreferences("userInfo", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(logging)
                    .addInterceptor(new AccessTokenInterceptor(preferences))
                    .build();
```

*There i use it to add to AccessTokentInterceptor
but it is not important*

The Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

Help me pls

Comment: AppSingleton it  another Singleton.And it doestnt work too

Comment: You shouldn't need a singleton just to get the Application instance, because `context` is available from Fragments, Activities, and AndroidViewModels already.

Answer (score 0):

AppSingleton.getInstance() is returning null.  Take a look at that class and see why it is null.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `onCreate()` method and assign the reference from there

```
class App: Application() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: App
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        instance = this
        super.onCreate()
    }
}
```